# how to offseting voltage for ph electrode?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ph

is it necessary to use circuit below for offseting? and what is the difference if I connect directly 512mv Voltage to my ph electrode?
[image]

Comment: The question is same with https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20918/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-op-amp

Answer (score 2):

A glass pH sensor has an output of (nominally) zero volts at a pH of 7, and a negative coefficient. So without an offset a single-supply circuit without an offset as shown would be unable to measure any pH greater then 7, since it cannot provide a negative output

An input offset of 512 mV gives you about a 500 mV margin for neutral solutions, and since the output sensitivity of a glass sensor is about -60 mV/pH, the circuit shown can read the pH of solutions up to about a pH of 16.

The reference amp is not strictly necessary, but buffering references is always a good idea, and should be the norm for high-precision circuits. What it does not do is provide useful temperature drift compensation. The LMP7721 input offset voltage only drifts about 1.5 uV/deg C, and the temperature characteristics of a pH cell change much more than this with temperature.

Comment: The input common mode range is -0.3V to 1V below the positive rail which is not specified.  Zero input is acceptable.

Comment: @KevinWhite - Ack! Boy, that was a brain fart. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you show can't possibly work.  It does not include a reference electrode, and the offset circuit is not needed.[image]

Comment: it actually has reference voltage !!!!!!!

Comment: Where?  Not in the schematic.